Google Earth Engine: inconsistent error when exporting to CSV "Error: Execution failed; out of memory. (Error code: 8)"
I have been working in Google Earth Engine to take a feature collection (timeseries_polygons) and then flatten it to export the resulting table to Google Drive as a CSV. I'm running this over hundreds of feature collections to export each individually. I'm doing this successfully using a for loop, though I know that's not best practice with GEE. These CSVs each typically have somewhere between 5,000 and 10,000 records.
In this process, I've run into some pretty inconsistent issues with exporting where this will work on a specific feature collection one time, but then I may come back to run it on the same exact feature collection later and it will fail (producing  "Error: Execution failed; out of memory. (Error code: 8)"). I tend to notice it fail more frequently after I've successfully exported hundreds of CSVs all at once.
I've tried to troubleshoot this in my code based on other posts here to no success, so I'm starting to think this may have to do with GEE's quotas. I don't think it's due to fixed memory quotas for individual exports since the exact same table will export successfully one time but fail another (i.e., the 'per request memory footprint' is the same, but will sometimes result in an error). But I'm wondering if GEE limits what/how much you can export after you've already exported a huge amount of data (in my case, hundreds of individual CSVs). Is that true and is there anything that can be done to address this?
The export within the for loop is pretty basic, and there don't seem to be any issues with the timeseries_polygons feature class:
// Flatten collection/remove geometry for export
var timeseries_flat= timeseries_polygons.flatten().select([".*"], null, false);

// Export csv of data summary to Google Drive folder
Export.table.toDrive(timeseries_flat, "timeseries_flat_1", 'exports-folder-in-drive');

